# Оксана и Ксения — разные имена или варианты одного имени?

Tags: ономастика

Часто слышу, когда Оксан называют Ксюшами. А, собственно, Оксана и Ксения — это разные имена или варианты одного имени, как, например, Елена и Алена?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Чаще всего в литературе прослеживается такое мнение: имена  Ксения и Оксана, а ещё к ним Аксинья – это родственные имена,  считаются  своеобразными вариантами друг для друга. Эти имена в современности употребляются независимо друг от друга. Например, для нотариуса это разные имена, там играет роль только имя по паспорту.

В быту используется полное имя Ксения -  греческого происхождения.  «Ксенос» — иностранка. Переводят его по-разному: гостеприимная, странница, чужестранка, гостья. Кроме русского часто встречается в польском, болгарском, сербском и других славянских языках. В православной традиции почитается несколько святых Ксений, отмечаются их именины. Уменьшительно-ласкательное - Ксюша, Ксеня и кому как угодно. Другие варианты этого имени – украинское Оксана (Ксана) и русское Аксинья. Уменьшительно-ласкательные варианты тоже возможны кому какие нравятся, лишь бы в корне "кс" было, не суть важно - это же разговорные, не официальные имена.

Answer (score 5):

Да, это именно очень близкая аналогия.
Алена (Олена) и Оксана - варианты греческих имен. 
Олена и Оксана - украинские, Алена и Арина (вместо Ирина) - русские.

Тут надо смотреть прежде всего, а что такое "разные" имена, какие на то критерии?
Просто "мнение" в литературе и быту тут не столь важно. Есть церковное канонизированное понимание того, что Оксаны суть Ксении, Арины - Ирины, Юрии и Егоры - Георгии и проч, поскольку крещены в память данных святых.

Что же касается всех других источников, то вопрос умозрителен. Так, по гражданскому праву все разно пишущиеся имена - разные (вплоть до Наталия - Наталья). Поэтому доказывать что-то бесполезно и бессодержательно иначе как в суде. Ну а все остальное - это уже просто досужие разговоры.

Answer (score 1):

Тут вся загвоздка в том , как первоначально звучало это имя у той христианской святой , и какова была национальная принадлежность этой святой . Согласно церковной версии (житие) ,  святая Ксения жила в Y веке , была дочерью римского сенатора и с рождения носила имя Евсевия , но , устремившись к Богу , покинула отчий дом и обосновалась в Милассе (Малая Азия) , где после сменила имя на Ксения . Y-й век это начальный период христианской истории , когда новая вера ещё только-только отпочковалась от иудаизма . Неслучайно историки называют этот период *иудеохристианством* . И его активисты были в подавляющем большинстве диаспорные евреи , а эпицентром распространения  христианского учения была Малая Азия . И имена эти первые святомученики носили еврейские . Это уже потом римско-византийские житописцы переделали их имена на греческий лад ; жития тоже подправляли . Ну , судите сами : как среди апостолов Христа могли оказаться "греки" Андрей , Пётр  и Филипп , если Христос напрямую заявлял о своей миссии : "Я пришёл к заблудшим овцам стада Израилева ." ; кроме того , 12-ть апостолов символизируют 12-ть израилевых колен , и греческие имена в числе этих 12-ти  совершенно неуместны . Здесь несомненно присутствует переделка имен по созвучию с еврейских на греческие . Имя Андрей в действительности  у этого апостола зучало как Хендре/Хендрик ; Пётр это в оригинале Патруш (есть и фамилии Петрашевский , Патрушев) ; про имя Филипп точно не знаю , но замечу , что наяду с фамилией Филипенко есть и фамилия Пилипенко , а ивритная буква пей **פ** может читаться и как **Ф** , и как **П** ,  . Теперь перейдём к святой Ксении . Её первое имя - Евсевия . Евсевий по хрестоматийной версии от греческого "*благочестивый*" . В действительности за именем святого Евсевия (обезглавлен в Никодимии в 303 году) скрывается еврейское имя Йешива . И своё второе имя святая Ксения носила тоже еврейское , типа Екшне или Окшен (фамилия Аксёнов) , которое потом христианские житописцы переделали на греческий лад , - "*гостья*" , "*чужая*" . Теперь возьмём имя Оксана , то бишь , Ксения по-украински . На Украине еврейское влияние было куда  сильнее , чем в России . **Поэтому украинская Оксана делалась не с общецерковной Ксении , а с  исходного ивритного варианта Екшне/Окшен** . То же самое с именем Афанасий , которое на Украине звучит как Панас : та же буква пей **פ** с двойным звучанием **Ф** и **П** , - украинцы предпочли исходный еврейский вариант , а не грекоподобную каноническую переделку . А вот другое характерное украинское имя - Остап (среди гетманов Зап.Сечи с пол-дюжины Остапов) . Распространена версия , что это украинский вариант имени Степан/Стефан . Я , однако , считаю , что здесь соответствие с именем Астафий ,ошибочно считающемся упрощённой формой от Евстафий (фамилия Астафьев достаточно распространена ) . И тут вариация **Ф** и **П** выдает еврейское происхождение имени . В мусульманском варианте это имя звучит как Мустафа (мусульмане добавили букву М ). А вот интересное украинское имя Хома , - помните Хому Философа из гоголевского "Вия" ? Это не есть украинский вариант имени Фома/Томас , -   мусульманское соответствие этому имени звучит как Туман (фамилия Туманов) . Хома (фамиия Хоменко) это самостоятельное еврейское имя , которому соответствует мусульманское имя Гумар/Омар , а также фамилии типа Комаровский , Комарин , Комарихин .

Comment: В разных местностях на Украине Ф и Х чередуются, иногда вместо Ф произносят ХВ, иногда, наоборот, вместо ХВІСТ говорят ФОСТ. Так что ХОМА это только ФОМА, иногда произносят ХВОМА, причем В - еле слышно, вроде ХУОМА.Еще КОМАРОВСКИЙ это "обрусевшая" польская фамилия КОМОРОВСКИЙ, возможно от КОМОРА(комнатка,чулан).С некоторыми остальными Вашими выводами тоже можно поспорить, но сейчас не готов.

Comment: Зайдите по ссылочке  http://jmemory.org/ , Вы попадете на "Электронную книгу памяти воинов-евреев , павших в боях с нацизмом (1941-1945)" . Там слева в столбце нажмите на строчку "Мемориал" , прокрутите страницу ниже , в поиске по буквам алфавита нажмите на "Ко" и просмотрите на по сочетанию КОМ- . Я  переписал для Вас : КОМАН Моисей Бенционович , КОМАРНИЦКИЙ Григорий Миронович ,  КОМАРНИЦКИЙ Меер Ефимович , КОМАРНИЦКИЙ Моисей Давидович , КОМАРОВСКИЙ Александр Лейбович, КОМАРОВСКИЙ Ефим Беньяминвич, КОМАРОВСКИЙ Ионтов Исаевич . Есть 16-ть КОММов , а также солдат-еврей КОМОРНИК Цудик Нутович .

Comment: Примечание :ивритная буква כ - звуки Х и К . Посмотрите в том же "Мемориале" относительно имени Панас на ПАН- . Тоже увидите таких евреев . И ещё : В ЭТОМ "МЕМОРИАЛЕ" ОЧЕНЬ МНОГО ФАМИЛИЙ ПО ОКС- И ОКСЕН- (также один Окснер) . Это применительно к украинскому имени ОКСАНА . Можете даже открыть биографические данные по этим солдатам-евреям .

Comment: Вам  бы  хорошо  почитать  книги  не  только  по  истории,  но  и  по  исторической  фонетике,  по  ономастике.

Comment: Вообще-то, иудеи были самыми ярыми преследователями христианства и инициаторами гонений. Так что, я бы не объединяла христиан с ними.

Comment: Fuchoin Kazuki утверждает , что я ошибочно объединяю христиан с иудеями , А я их вовсе не объединяю, и Вы , матушка , просто не поняли или невнимательно читали . Христианство отпочковалось от иудейской религии , и это суть общепринятая историческая точка зрения . А топор войны , действительно первыми бросили иудеи , создав Талмуд , объявивший Иисуса лжепророком . Но на уровне национальной самоидентификации процесс прошёл не мгновенно (иначе и быть не могло !) , - евреи-христиане ещё долго-долго продолжали считать себя евреями , а не выхристами , сменившими национальную принадлежность .

Comment: bernard рекомендует мне ознакомиться с теоретическими работами по лингвистике . Да , я не профессиональный языковед , а также и не профессиональный историк , и не имею академического образования по этим наукам . Однако , попробуйте , батенька , опровергнуть мою точку зрения на основе этой самой исторической фонетики и ономастики , а не просто указанием на эти науки ! А я , со своей стороны , советую Вам  поинтересоваться темой взаимодействия евреев и славянских народов . Ну , начните хотя бы вот с этой ссылочки http://zarubezhom.com/Onomastics.htm  - хотя тут есть некоторые ошибки  .

Comment: Относительно вашей «ссылочки»: с такими материалами надо осторожнее, рекомендуйте только ближнему кругу,— не забросают стульями хотя бы. Гнусный текст.