# АлЁна и АлЕна есть ли имя Алена с произношением через Е(йэ)

Tags: ономастика

скажите существует ли имя АлЕна с произношением через Е(йэ). Допустим в паспорте у некоторых записано АлЕна без точек может ли быть произношение у разных носителей этого имени по разному то есть для кого то это именно АлЁна через Ё(йо) а для других носителей это АлЕна через Е(йэ). Есть ли вообще такое имя АлЕна через Е(йэ) произношение. В интернете нашел сайт вот этот и не понял конкретно как это понять вот ссылка: https://m.newizv.ru/news/society/20-04-2018/sud-priznal-chto-alyona-i-alena-raznye-imena?id=sud-priznal-chto-alyona-i-alena-raznye-imena&published_date=20-04-2018&rubric=society&type=NewsItem Объясните пожалуйста поподробнее. Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В словарях русских личных имен полное имя "Алена" не зафиксировано, "Алёна" приведено как форма имени "Елена". Однако в бытовом употреблении (суд сослался на "Словарь **народных** форм русских имен") такая форма имени вполне возможна.

Также нужно заметить, что в большинстве стран не существует никаких правил об именовании детей только словарными именами. Поэтому никто не вправе воспрепятствовать тому, чтобы в свидетельстве о рождении записали именно "Алена" как полное имя.

Носитель такого имени может настаивать на том, чтобы его имя произносили через "е", но нужно быть готовым к тому, что в подавляющем числе случаев его будут произносить через "ё", что определяется вековыми традициями.

Comment: А Роман, значит, так, для маскировки.)))

Comment: И вот еще что нашел, оказывается в белоруссии имя Елена с русского переводится как АлЕна с произношением именно через Е(йэ) вот ссылка на этот сайт:  eva.ru/beauty/messages-3415006.htm  Только вот непойму с русскими именами это как то связано или нет? 
Вот ссылка на ее коментарий: Kосатка ** 19.02 23:53 #91905221 ответ на #91903630 А я вот Елена на самом деле, а на латинице у меня прописано Аlena. Вот на русском я Елена, а на латинице так, потому что у нас переводят с белорусского. В белорусском имя Елена, это АлЕна, именно через Е произносится, а не через Ё.

Comment: Артём, что Вы имеете ввиду так, для маскировки, я просто непонял, поясните пожалуйста?))

Comment: Роман, этот ресурс посвящен русскому языку; я отвечал исключительно про русские имена. А вообще в России более 150 национальностей, так что не удивительно, если в каких-то из них есть имя Алена через "е".

Comment: @Роман: ой, простите, Роман! Только сейчас заметил, что вы цитируете, сначала подумал, что это вы Елена/Алена.)))

Comment: И вот еще что странно, почему то во всех словарях русских личных имен именно АлЁна через Ё(йо) указано что произошла от имени Елена, а тут: https://m.newizv.ru/news/society/20-04-2018/sud-priznal-chto-alyona-i-alena-raznye-imena?id=sud-priznal-chto-alyona-i-alena-raznye-imena&published_date=20-04-2018&rubric=society&type=NewsItem они пишут, что имя АлЕна через Е(йэ) произошла от имени Елена... А имя АлЁна через Ё(йо) от имён Александра и Алла... Почему так? Может быть они что то перепутали с точками над Е?

Comment: Позвольте вмешаться? Роман, у вас очень много рассуждений что называется "ниачом". Основное по теме: решение суда вообще нельзя комментировать, не видя его. Почти наверняка оно посвящено какому-то конкретному вопросу, когда человек вынужден доказывать что документы именно ему принадлежат.   Или наоборот, что они сделаны с ошибкой - и подлежат переоформлению. Все остальное - рассуждения досужих журналистов. А ЗАГСы и прочие органы по таким заметкам не работают.

Comment: Короче, из затронутых вами (и самим аскером) тем имеет смысл обсуждать только правовые последствия такого решения суда. А само это решение вообще не обозначено в явном виде. Все же ваши "почему так" - это уровень "почемучек" из старшей группы детского сада.

Comment: *Однако в бытовом употреблении (суд сослался на "Словарь народных форм русских имен") такая форма имени вполне возможна* - Какое дело суду до бытового употребления??? Вы в каком-то параллельном мире живете, судя по такми заявлениям.

Answer (score 0):

Переношу сюда из закрытого "дубликата". 
[Имя АлЕна или АлЁна произошло и является производным от имени Елена?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460252)

Вы очень много вопросов задаете. Еще и начинающихся "с почему?" - обычно они не предполагают внятного ответа. А ведь все построено на каком-то не очень понятном решении суда, упоминаемом в материале по вашей ссылке. Без него и не особо понятно, о чем вообще речь.

Поэтому позвольте мне их переформулировать так, чтобы можно было ответить.

**1. Как прокомментировать решение суда о признании Имен Алена и Алена разными? А заодно  и имен Наталия и Наталья и подобных пар.**

Решение спорное, чем бы оно ни мотивировалось. Но здесь нет хорошего решения. на практике любое решение заставит кого-то доказывать свою, если так можно выразиться, "идентичность" в судебном же порядке.

**2. Зачем вообще это нужно и какую силу имеют подобные решения**

Никакой, кроме вопросов идентификации, судебных и нотариальных. А в документах все должно быть строго, так что Наталья и Наталия с точки зрения работника загса - имена действительно разные, для этого и суда не надо. В отношении Алена и Алёна - вопрос, как уже сказал, неоднозначен. Практика использования буквы Ё не дает оснований считать эти имена разными  с точки зрения гражданского права.

**3. Суд якобы ссылается на мнение Суперанской (без пруфа), что это имена разные по происхождению. Так ли это?**
Не знаю, похоже решение суда просто прокомментировали. Вряд ли суд вообще озаботится мнением филолога в этом вопросе, для них интересно не происхождение имен, а правоприменительная практика по отношению к именам как к данности.

**4. Верна ли вообще посылка, приписываемая Суперанской?**
Я у неё такого не видел, возможно и передернули. Но вообще-то к её мнению надо относится с осторожностью. 
Хоть каким-то авторитетом тут может служить только Церковь, которая всех Ален, как бы они не писались, причисляет к Еленам. Там это важно, поскольку надо дни Ангела (именины) отмечать. В остальных ситуациях вопрос никого особо не волнует.

Если что не учел из вашего списка вопросов, спрашивайте в комментариях.

ПС
Вообще-то подобные вопросы на ресурсе - не редкость, я поищу чуть позже. Или сами попробуйте.
Вот один сразу и попался. 
[Оксана и Ксения — разные имена или варианты одного имени?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/31012)
Посмотрите - я там тоже отвечал нечто подобное. Без отсылки к суду, понятно.