# Имя АлЕна или АлЁна произошло и является производным от имени Елена?

Tags: орфография, этимология, ономастика

Вопрос в следующем, почему то во всех словарях русских личных имен именно АлЁна через Ё(йо) указана что произошла от имени Елена, а тут: https://m.newizv.ru/news/society/20-04-2018/sud-priznal-chto-alyona-i-alena-raznye-imena?id=sud-priznal-chto-alyona-i-alena-raznye-imena&published_date=20-04-2018&rubric=society&type=NewsItem они пишут, что имя АлЕна через Е(йэ) произошла от имени Елена... А имя АлЁна через Ё(йо) от имён Александра и Алла... Почему так? Может быть они что то перепутали с точками над Е?... Дак всё таки АлЕна или АлЁна произошла от имени Елена? АлЕна или АлЁна производное имя от имени Елена? И есть ли вообще такое имя АлЕна, через Е(йэ) произношением?

Answer (score 0):

Вы очень много вопросов задаете. Еще и начинающихся "с почему?" - обычно они не предполагают внятного ответа. А ведь все построено на каком-то не очень понятном решении суда, упоминаемом в материале по вашей ссылке. Без него и не особо понятно, о чем вообще речь.

Поэтому позвольте мне их переформулировать так, чтобы можно было ответить.

**1. Как прокомментировать решение суда о признании Имен Алена и Алена разными? А заодно  и имен Наталия и Наталья и подобных пар.**

Решение спорное, чем бы оно ни мотивировалось. Но здесь нет хорошего решения. на практике любое решение заставит кого-то доказывать свою, если так можно выразиться, "идентичность" в судебном же порядке.

**2. Зачем вообще это нужно и какую силу имеют подобные решения**

Никакой, кроме вопросов идентификации, судебных и нотариальных. А в документах все должно быть строго, так что Наталья и Наталия с точки зрения работника загса - имена действительно разные, для этого и суда не надо. В отношении Алена и Алёна - вопрос, как уже сказал, неоднозначен. Практика использования буквы Ё не дает оснований считать эти имена разными  с точки зрения гражданского права.

**3. Суд якобы ссылается на мнение Суперанской (без пруфа), что это имена разные по происхождению. Так ли это?**
Не знаю, похоже решение суда просто прокомментировали. Вряд ли суд вообще озаботится мнением филолога в этом вопросе, для них интересно не происхождение имен, а правоприменительная практика по отношению к именам как к данности.

**4. Верна ли вообще посылка, приписываемая Суперанской?**
Я у неё такого не видел, возможно и передернули. Но вообще-то к её мнению надо относится с осторожностью. 
Хоть каким-то авторитетом тут может служить только Церковь, которая всех Ален, как бы они не писались, причисляет к Еленам. Там это важно, поскольку надо дни Ангела (именины) отмечать. В остальных ситуациях вопрос никого особо не волнует.

Если что не учел из вашего списка вопросов, спрашивайте в комментариях.

ПС
Вообще-то подобные вопросы на ресурсе - не редкость, я поищу чуть позже. Или сами попробуйте.
Вот один сразу и попался. 
[Оксана и Ксения — разные имена или варианты одного имени?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/31012)
Посмотрите - я там тоже отвечал нечто подобное. Без отсылки к суду, понятно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я вас понимаю измучал этими вопросами, просто одно не вяжется с другим на разных ресурсах, вот и логически я был поставлен в тупик, поэтому хотелось узнать от Вас как же все таки на самом деле, ну если что то еще найдете то буду благодарен, добавляйте комментарий, буду признателен! Благодарю за Ваш ответ... Вот это же нашел: https://m.9111.ru/questions/777777777313959/ и вот еще из Подробнее>>> с этого же сайта: https://documentcloud.adobe.com/link/review?uri=urn%3Aaaid%3Ascds%3AUS%3A77dd998a-a84c-4b71-9d61-89db28607daf - Посмотрите эту ссылку пожалуйста...

Comment: Не поняли. Здесь готовы ответить на любые вопросы по теме русского языка, просто их надо задавать нормально. Внятно и не валить все в одну кучу. Поискать вы и сами можете. осваивайте функционал ресурса.

Comment: А вот насчет "на разных ресурсах"... Это из серии "на сарае тоже написано". Не заморачивайтесь сведениями из неавторитетных источников.